# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'point1_x' referenced before assignment when using plotty quiver plot in dash app

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I kind of new to plotty, and see the error msg of

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "visualize_test.py", line 134, in update_graph
    quiver_fig = ff.create_quiver(-pos_y, pos_x, -vel_y, vel_x)
  File "python/__pypackages__/3.8/lib/plotly/figure_factory/_quiver.py", line 104, in create_quiver
    quiver_obj = _Quiver(x, y, u, v, scale, arrow_scale, angle)
  File "/python/__pypackages__/3.8/lib/plotly/figure_factory/_quiver.py", line 165, in __init__
    arrow_x, arrow_y = self.get_quiver_arrows()
  File "/python/__pypackages__/3.8/lib/plotly/figure_factory/_quiver.py", line 265, in get_quiver_arrows
    arrow_x = utils.flatten(zip(point1_x, self.end_x, point2_x, empty))
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'point1_x' referenced before assignment in the below code snippet.
```

And I really stuck here for a few hours, need some help to spot the bug here, thx!
The code basically read x, y position and corresponding velocity from data stream, append to list and change to np.array and invoke ff.create_quiver from figure_factory

```py
# Define the callback function to update the graph
@app.callback([Output('Track', 'figure'), [Input('frame-slider', 'value')])
def update_graph(selected_frame):
    
    fig1 = go.Figure()
    index = selected_frame - start_index
    
    pos_x = []
    pos_y = []
    vel_x = []
    vel_y = []
    
    for track_index, track in enumerate(tracker_output[index]):
        pos = track.body_frame_pos
        vel = track.body_frame_vel
        
        pos_x.append(pos[0])
        pos_y.append(pos[1])
        vel_x.append(vel[0])
        vel_y.append(vel[1])
        
    pos_x = np.array(pos_x)
    pos_y = np.array(pos_y)
    vel_x = np.array(vel_x)
    vel_y = np.array(vel_y)

    quiver_fig = ff.create_quiver(pos_x, pos_y, vel_x, vel_y)
    
    fig1.add_traces(data = quiver_fig.data)

    fig1.update_layout(
        title={'text': f'Track at Frame {selected_frame}'},
        xaxis={'title': 'lateral pos', 'range': [-30, 30]},  # Set X axis limits
        yaxis={'title': 'long pos', 'range': [-2, 50]}   # Set Y axis limits
    )
```

the array shape is fine, I even print it out after below line.

```
pos_x = np.array(pos_x)
pos_y = np.array(pos_y)
vel_x = np.array(vel_x)
vel_y = np.array(vel_y),
```

the shape is `(0, )` though, not sure that is the issue....

Comment: (1) Format the code properly. (2) Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text (formatted as code) in the question.

Comment: Are you sure you posted the relevant code ? The error message mentions that a variable named `point1_x` is referenced before being initialized. I don't see any reference to this variable in your code.

Comment: has updated the traceback for the error

Comment: It seems that `tracker_output[index]` is empty, this causes empty pos and vel arrays which causes the (not very helpful) error.

Comment: Note that all of the callbacks in a Dash app are (by default) executed with the initial value of their inputs when the app is first loaded, so if 'frame-slider' is inserted into the layout without an initial value, and unless you specified `prevent_initial_callbacks=True` when instantiating the app, the callback is initially called with `selected_frame` set to `None`, which might be the source of the issue.